# Simplify the SQL statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the table `event_temperature`, a record is the temperature record of an employee at a certain time:

```
event_id, dept_name, event_card, temp, event_time

9394cf697afa11ea9562040e3c15002f, BU003, F9011101, 36.7000, 2020-04-08 06:50:01
9394cecc7afa11ea9562040e3c15002f, BU003, F9011101, 37.2000, 2020-04-11 07:50:17
907ebe3f7afa11ea9562040e3c15002f, BU003, W4204094, 40.3000, 2020-04-10 08:35:45
8fdf42a07afa11ea9562040e3c15002f, BU007, F1644194, 36.1600, 2020-04-07 19:58:08
8e9bb6fd7afa11ea9562040e3c15002f, BU003, F2150829, 35.8000, 2020-04-11 12:45:23
```

Now I want to get the number of these 3 types of employees in each department of today：

1. total: all temperature
2. abnormal: temperature between 37.3 and 42
3. suspect: temperature between 36.5 and 37.3

I have write this SQL, but it looks to miscellaneous:

```sql
SELECT 
    ee1.dept_name, ee1.total, ee2.abnormal, ee3.suspect
FROM
    (SELECT 
        ee.dept_name, COUNT(DISTINCT ee.event_card) AS total
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
        et.dept_name,
            et.event_card,
            CASE
                WHEN et.temp BETWEEN 36.5 AND 37.3 THEN 'suspect'
                WHEN et.temp BETWEEN 37.3 AND 42 THEN 'abnormal'
                ELSE 'normal'
            END AS type_
    FROM
        `whsgdb-dev`.event_temperature et
    WHERE
        et.event_time BETWEEN '2020-04-11 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-11 23:59:59') ee
    GROUP BY ee.dept_name) ee1
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        ee.dept_name, COUNT(DISTINCT ee.event_card) AS abnormal
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
        et.dept_name,
            et.event_card,
            CASE
                WHEN et.temp BETWEEN 36.5 AND 37.3 THEN 'suspect'
                WHEN et.temp BETWEEN 37.3 AND 42 THEN 'abnormal'
                ELSE 'normal'
            END AS type_
    FROM
        `whsgdb-dev`.event_temperature et
    WHERE
        et.event_time BETWEEN '2020-04-11 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-11 23:59:59') ee
    WHERE
        ee.type_ = 'abnormal'
    GROUP BY ee.dept_name) ee2 ON ee2.dept_name = ee1.dept_name
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        ee.dept_name, COUNT(DISTINCT ee.event_card) AS suspect
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT
        et.dept_name,
            et.event_card,
            CASE
                WHEN et.temp BETWEEN 36.5 AND 37.3 THEN 'suspect'
                WHEN et.temp BETWEEN 37.3 AND 42 THEN 'abnormal'
                ELSE 'normal'
            END AS type_
    FROM
        `whsgdb-dev`.event_temperature et
    WHERE
        et.event_time BETWEEN '2020-04-11 00:00:00' AND '2020-04-11 23:59:59') ee
    WHERE
        ee.type_ = 'suspect'
    GROUP BY ee.dept_name) ee3 ON ee3.dept_name = ee1.dept_name
```

Result:

```
dept_name, total, abnormal, suspect

BU003, 3227, null, 6
BU007, 247, null, 2
BU011, 16, null, 1
```

Please help me simplify the sql statement, or is there a simpler way？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
    dept_name,
    COUNT(DISTINCT event_card) AS total,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN temp BETWEEN 37.3 AND 42   THEN event_card END) AS abnormal,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN temp BETWEEN 36.5 AND 37.3 THEN event_card END) AS suspect
FROM event_temperature
WHERE
    event_time >= CURDATE() && event_time < (CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY
    dept_name
ORDER BY
    dept_name;
```

Comment: Each employee may have multiple records，where to add the DISTINCT

Comment: Then you should be counting distinct event cards, see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome, it works. You forgot to write `from event_temperature` (: